# Validating a phone number in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2010

I want to be able to accept any way that a user inputs their phone number. I need help to include regular expressions that can validate the length of a  number, bracket, hyphens and take care of spaces.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will not do your homework for you. Please show us a sincere effort that you've made to solve the problem yourself, and we'll help you solve the problems you're having with that. For more about how this site works, [please read the help docs.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Good luck with your education. You will need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
function Myfuc() {
    var x = document.forms[0]["mobile"].value;
    var z = document.forms[0]["mobile1"].value;
if(x == null || x == '')
    {
        alert("Field canot be empty");
        return false;
    }

    if(x[0]!=0) // Starting with zero
    {
        alert("Mobile number should start with Zero");
        return false;
    }
    var y=isNaN(x); // Checking numerals in first text box
    if(y == true)
    {
        alert("Integers only accepted");
        return false;
    }
    var z1=isNaN(z); // Checking numerals in first text box
    if(z1 == true)
    {
        alert("Integers only accepted");
        return false;
    }

   }
</script>

<form onsubmit="Myfuc()">
Mobile : <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" style="width:40px;" maxlength=3> -
<input type="text" name="mobile1" maxlength=7>

<input type="submit" value="Click" name="sub" >

</form>
```

Everything you asked is here!!!, Spent 1 hr for this and imma beginner, dont worry code works well :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! I used this code and formatted it into the site and after some work it finally worked like I wanted it to ^^ :)))

Answer (score 0):

You could use this reg expression. I'm not too good with reg expressions but this could work in your case.

```
0\d{2}-\d{7}

/* start match with 0
   check for 2 additional digits
   check for hyphen
   check for 7 additional digits after hyphen
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I also suck at creating regex expressions; however, you can always do something like this:

```
var str = document.getElementById('myInput').value,
numberOnly = str.replace(/-/g, ''),
errors = [], i;

if (isNaN(numberOnly)) {
    errors.push('You must use numbers!');
} else if (str.split('-')[0].length !== 3 || str.split('-')[1] !== 7 || numberOnly > 10) {
    errors.push('Invalid Format!');
} else {
    console.log(numberOnly + ' is ok!');
}

if (errors) {
    for (i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
        console.log(i + '. ' + errors[i]);
    }
}
```

It's simply testing each part of the string that is submitted.

First it checks to see (after we remove the hyphen) that the submitted value is actually a number.

Second, it splits the string in half to check if the start of the string has 3 characters, and then if the end of the string has 7 characters; lastly, it tests to see if the number is too large... etc, you can even check if its too small.

If you ever figure out a decent regex, you could instead use a switch statement to catch the errors (if any).

I think one might look like, [0-9]{3}(-)[0-9]{7} or something like that lol.

-

I've been working with PHP for awhile, so I forget if "length" returns a count, or the actual byte-size of a character, e.g. "é" is 2 bytes.

EDIT:

To check if the first character of the string is "0", you can always do:

```
if (str.length > 0 && str.charAt(0) != 0) { console.log('error'); }
```